# google map is not diplaying markers

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I am using the code directly from Google.
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3?csw=1

I modified slightly to use my database. The map displays on the page and if I run the XML generator - it properly displays the XML.

I've done a search on here extensively and attempted to make the changes suggested - however, I cannot get the markers to display on the Google Map?

```
 <?php

    $state= "CA";
    $country= "US";

    require("phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php");

    // Opens a connection to a mySQL server
    $connection=mysql_connect (localhost, $username, $password);
    if (!$connection) {
      die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
    }

    // Set the active mySQL database
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
    if (!$db_selected) {
      die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $sql1 = "SELECT avg(lat), avg(lng) FROM marker WHERE country='$country' && state='$state'";
    $res1 = mysql_query($sql1); 
    $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($res1);
    $alat = $row1[0];
    $alng = $row1[1];
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html >
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>PHP/MySQL & Google Maps Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    var customIcons = {
      free: {
        icon: '/images/blue.png'
      },
      paid: {
        icon: '/images/red.png'
      }
    };

    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(<? echo $alat; ?>, <? echo $alng; ?>),
        zoom: 6,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); 

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var icon = eval('customIcons'+'.'+type) || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="load()">
   <div align="center">
    <div id="map" style="width: 1024px; height: 600px"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

The file used to generate the XML:

```
<?php

require("phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php");

// Start XML file, create parent node

$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server

$connection=mysql_connect ('localhost', $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());}

// Set the active MySQL database

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Select all the rows in the markers table

$query = "SELECT * FROM marker WHERE country='$country' && state='$state'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("type", $row['type']);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();

?>
```

I did see one explanation but I didn't understand what it meant.
"The file has to be hosted on the web server instead of the file system."

I am attempting to run this on a website; the files are not stored on my computer but on the server.

Any additional assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you see when you call **phpsqlajax_genxml.php** in your browser? When you've stored the files on the server, is there also a table with the desired data?

Comment: I see a list of xml desired data.
<markers>
<marker name="VFW POST 8620" address="2328 W. Merced Ave" lat="34.069485" lng="-117.958099" type="free"/>
<marker name="Tamarack" address="9257 Slauson Ave Pico Rivera, CA 90660" lat="33.969315" lng="-118.098984" type="free"/>
<marker name="Brunswick Foothill Lanes" address="17238 E Foothill Blvd" lat="34.106903" lng="-117.428169" type="free"/>
<marker name="kokopellis kantina" address="57154 29 Palms Hwy." lat="34.122791" lng="-116.417328" type="free"/>
...
</markers>

Comment: works for me with the given xml....check if the icon-URLs are correct

Answer (score 0):

replace your script with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code
Replace your xml file code.
<?php

function parseToXML($htmlStr) 
{ 
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr); 
return $xmlStr; 
} 

$connection=mysql_connect (localhost, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

echo '<markers>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
  echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
  echo 'type="' . $row['type'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';
}
echo '</markers>';

?>
```

Comment: Produced the same results, as the other XML code. Still no markers.